# How to count a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$fruits = array("banana", "pineapple", array("apple", "mango"), "guava");
echo count($fruits,1);
```

The above code outputs 6, but I don't understand why. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: 4 for the first level and 2 for second .. also the array  is an elem ..

Comment: Upvote simply because this is the first time I've realized that `count()` can take a second parameter.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus same here! Although I think it would be more useful if the recursive count didn't include the inner arrays. Maybe I'm missing some value of that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I was juggling that thought as well but I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027183/2191572 explains it nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fruits = array("banana", "pineapple", array("apple", "mango"), "guava");
```

Because is counting the `array("apple","mango")` as 1 element

```
count($fruits,1)// the second parameter will recursively count the array

+ 1 -> banana
+ 1 -> pineapple
+ 1 -> array("apple","mango")
+ 1 --------> apple
+ 1 --------> mango
+ 1 -> guava
____
 6 elements
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will help

```
$fruits = array("banana", "pineapple", array("apple", "mango"), "guava");

foreach ($fruits as $key => $value)
{
   echo count($value) . "<br />";
}

// Output : 1 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expected it to return 5, it's because the array on the 3rd position is counted as an element. If you expected it to return 4, [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)'s second argument specifies whether it should count recursively or not.

Answer (score 0):

`array("apple","mango")` counts as 3, since you're deep counting.

It first counts "banana", "pineapple", array(), "guava"
Then "apple" and "mango"

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the leaf nodes, you can take advantage of the fact that `array_walk_recursive` only touches those.

```
array_walk_recursive($fruits, function() use (&$count) { $count++; });
echo $count;  // 5
```